# Not getting distinct results using case query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the query I am running. I am getting the correct results except they come in on a different line for each corpstorenum,
so i am getting :

```
Corpstorenum,BuffetYN, deliverybeeryn, dineinbeeryn,saladbar
store1,n,n,n,y
store1,n,n,y,n
store1,n,y,n,n
store1,n,n,n,n
```

instead of:

```
store1 n,y,y,y
```

This is my code:

```
select distinct corpstorenum,
case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='buffetAY' then 'Y' else 'n' end as BuffetYN ,
    case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='Beer' and delivery#>0 then 'Y' else 'n' end as DeliveryBeerYN ,
    case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='Beer' and dinein#>0 then 'Y' else 'n' end as DineInBeerYN,
    case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and menusize='WithMeal' and dinein#>0 then 'Y' 
else 'n' end as SaladBar 
from storenumbers 
    left join prod5219 on storenumbers.storenumber = [Prod5219].store
```

Comment: Without a data sample to look at, it's hard to say, but it seems like there are multiple records in your [storenumbers] table (or [prod5219] table) that match, and if so it makes sense that you would get multiple rows.  What you probably want is a query that checks the existence of a field value instead of a join.

Comment: @Jeff - welcome to [dba.se] - please take a quick look at the [tour] and read about how to create a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/mcve) when posting questions with code.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple rows in `prod5219` for store `store1`, and each row has a unique set of values for `concept` and `menusize`.

Run this to check that out:

```
select storenumbers.*
    , prod5219.concept
    , prod5219.menusize
from storenumbers 
    left join prod5219 on storenumbers.storenumber = [Prod5219].store
```

Simply adding `distinct` to the `select` clause doesn't magically remove "extra" rows from the output.  `distinct` simply returns rows that are unique, across all columns returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but I assume that you would like 'Y'  if that exists. Since 'Y' > 'n' you can use max as an aggregate function. I.e.

```
select corpstorenum
      , max(case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='buffetAY' 
                 then 'Y' else 'n' end) as BuffetYN 
      , max(case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='Beer' and delivery#>0 
                 then 'Y' else 'n' end) as DeliveryBeerYN 
      , max(case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and concept ='Beer' and dinein#>0 
                 then 'Y' else 'n' end) as DineInBeerYN
      , max(case when storenumbers.storenumber is not null and menusize='WithMeal' and dinein#>0 
                 then 'Y' else 'n' end) as SaladBar 
from storenumbers 
left join prod5219 
    on storenumbers.storenumber = [Prod5219].store 
group by corpstorenum
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you might want to re-write your query to just check for the existence of records.  Something like the following (just an example, change as needed or if the tables are reversed).

```
SELECT p.corpstorenum,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [storenumbers] WHERE storenumber = p.store AND concept = 'buffetAY') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'n' END AS BuffetYN,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [storenumbers] WHERE storenumber = p.store AND concept = 'beer' and delivery#>0) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'n' END AS DeliveryBeerYN,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [storenumbers] WHERE storenumber = p.store AND concept = 'beer' AND dinein#>0) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'n' END AS DineInBeerYN,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [storenumbers] WHERE storenumber = p.store AND menusize='WithMeal' and dinein#>0) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'n' END AS SaladBar
FROM prod5219 p
```